# Failing at changing the text color in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to change the text color in a bootstrap template's navbar and have been unsuccessful. Anyone know where I'm going wrong? Here is my code.

```
<!--navbar-->
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner" id="nav-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Restaurant</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret">   </b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-search pull-right" action="">
          <input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
      </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
<!--navbar-->
```

The CSS:

```css
.navbar-inner {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

I also tried this:

```css
#nav-inner {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer & rate it if it helps. :)

Comment: Please consider recommending maackle's answer. It is the recommended way to handle custom CSS rules.

Comment: So does mine ;) and answers the question appropriately :P

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to change the css for the tabs you need to add `color: #ddd;` to the following

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    float: none;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding: 9px 10px 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color:  #ddd;
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but I would prefer making and linking a custom CSS file. In this file you can add or overwrite properties of the theme. Even when you update the theme, this will most likely still work. Just add the following line to 'customstyle.css': .navbar .nav > li > a {
  color: #ddd;
}

Answer (score 13):

My guess is that Bootstrap defines a more specific CSS rule that is winning out over your more general rule.  You should examine the page with Firefox or Chrome's developer tools to see which styles are winning out over others.  If your style doesn't even show up, then you know there's a more basic problem, but if Bootstrap's style is overriding your color, you have to give your style a higher precedence.

For a sanity check, try this overkill rule:

```css
html body .navbar .navbar-inner .container {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

And if that works, then experiment with a lower level of specificity to see how specific you really need to get.

If all else fails, you can always do:

```css
color: #FFF !important;
```

The [CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) lays this out in detail.

Comment: I don't know why the other answer was accepted, but this one is better. Don't go messing in themes, when you can overwrite properties in a custom css definition. MAKE SURE TO LINK YOUR CUSTOM CSS *AFTER* THE BOOTSTRAP THEME.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    float: none;
    color: #5FC8D6;
    background-color: #002E36;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
    float: none;
    color: #002E36;
    background-color: #5FC8D6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works... try it out.......

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:link
{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is going on in your code, to help others.
How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Works like a charm! Found it on another thread, so am not taking credit for it.